# Screenshot Desktop DirectX C++/QT

Tags: c++, qt, directx, screenshot

I'm trying to make a simple code in C++ to make a screenshot and get the buffer of pixels (RGB).
I'm using DirectX but I got a segmentation fault. I followed some code I found but nothing.

here is my code :

```
static void* pBits;
static IDirect3DDevice9* g_pd3dDevice;

void Screenshot::dxCaptureScreen() {
IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface;
g_pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(_screenWidth, _screenHeight, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SCRATCH, &pSurface, NULL); //Segfault here.
g_pd3dDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);
D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
pSurface->LockRect(&lockedRect, NULL, D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE | D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK | D3DLOCK_READONLY);

for (int i = 0; i < _screenHeight; i++) {
    memcpy((BYTE*)pBits + i * _screenWidth * 32 / 8, (BYTE*) lockedRect.pBits + i * lockedRect.Pitch, _screenWidth * 32 / 8);
}
pSurface->UnlockRect();
pSurface->Release();

}
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem on how to take screenshot with DirectX, here is my code :

```
int Screenshot::dxCaptureScreen() {
int                      ret = 0;

IDirect3DDevice9        *g_pd3dDevice;
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS   d3dpp;
IDirect3D9              *g_pD3D = NULL;
IDirect3DSurface9       *pSurface;
D3DLOCKED_RECT          lockedRect;

g_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

if (g_pD3D == NULL)
    return 0;

ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));

d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
d3dpp.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
d3dpp.MultiSampleQuality = 0;
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hDesktopWnd;
d3dpp.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;
d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;
d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT;

if ((ret = g_pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hDesktopWnd, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice)) != D3D_OK)
    return ret;
if ((ret = g_pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(_screenWidth, _screenHeight, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SCRATCH, &pSurface, NULL)) != D3D_OK)
    return ret;
if ((ret = g_pd3dDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface)) != D3D_OK)
    return ret;

pSurface->LockRect(&lockedRect, NULL, D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE | D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK | D3DLOCK_READONLY);
for (int i = 0; i < _screenHeight; i++) {
    memcpy(pPixels + i * _screenWidth * 32 / 8, (BYTE*) lockedRect.pBits + i * lockedRect.Pitch, _screenWidth * 32 / 8);
}
```

I noticed it not very fast... With GDI Windows it takes less time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a QQuickWindow and a handle to it, and you want to capture what is visible in that window, you can simply do this:

```
QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(mYourWindowHandle);
QPixmap screenshot = window->grabWindow();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this way in QT, problem is that I want to call this function a lot and send images via sockets to simulate a mirroring in other device. So I'm looking for efficiency... I wanted to use DirectX

Comment: @DevAndroid, you'll probably find that sending the images and or compressing them will take much longer than the screenshot and would be better looking at optimisation after developing your solution with Qt handling capturing the screen.

Comment: That's true, I will use something totally different. I will send only when there is a movement and pixels change on the screen... It would be better and more efficient.